# How do you host a jekyll site to hostgator via FTP

Tags: html, css, ftp, hosting, jekyll

Hello i have tried to host my site that i build with jekyll via FTP. But when i put in my _site files, it seems like my javascript and css disappears and it looks terrible do any of you guys/girls out there know what i should do? :)

Comment: check out this link may be http://jekyllrb.com/docs/deployment-methods/

Comment: I just checked it out and it helped me :)

Comment: Thanks my site is working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to change the url that you call your css and js files with your new IP or domain.

Comment: but how should i change it? :)

Comment: Sorry, but i don´t know about jekyll. Maybe it would help you [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/01/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/) :)

Comment: Alright it is working now but now the problem is my font-awesome icons, they wont load into my site, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: never mind it is working now